# How to have i18n with angular-cli using JIT compiler

Tags: internationalization, angular-cli, jit

I would like to have i18n in my app, but I don't want to have to specify the language everytime I want to compile my app. I have read on the angular-cli doc that using a JIT compiler, it was possible to have the compiler search for the user's default language while compiling and translating the app accordingly. Unfortunately the doc doesn't elaborate on the subject of JIT.
Do someone has an idea about how to implement it ?